# How to deploy a React js .Net Core app in git repository in heroku

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, heroku, .net-core

I'm using heroku for the first time!
I created a React js .Net Core app in visual studio (with the repository on git), but when I try to deploy it in heroku, this error appears:
[image]

I have this buildpacks too:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Also tried buildpacks like this:
[image]

but shows this error:
[image]

Note:
With a normal React app it works, but I can't with React .Net Core

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but note that this isn't a Git issue: Git is acting as a transport for Heroku, shuffling your code over to Heroku and then shuffling Heroku's responses back to you. The `! Push failed` is from *Heroku*, not from Git (Git then obeys Heroku's command not to accept the push, but that's because of Heroku, not because of Git).

Comment: Meanwhile, the `npm: not found` implies that npm is not installed somewhere. Where (and how you should install it there), I don't know.

Comment: @torek Thank you for reply. In Reactjs .Net Core the npm files (like package.json) are inside ClientApp folder and not in root, I'm thinking if can be because of it... But I can't find a solution